# Creating a comment section for a PHP webpage

Tags: php, html, comments

I am trying to create a commenting area for a php webpage.

I was following along [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4BkHj7Ws9U) video (I only followed the code because I don't know the creator's language) and the code doesn't seem to work.

Here is the PHP bit of the code (modified), which is where the runtime errors are telling me there's something wrong. I commented the lines which give an error:

```
<?php
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $url = $_POST["url"];
        $message = $_POST["message"];
        $post = $_POST["post"];

        if($post){

        $write = fopen("../database/fnaticcomments.txt", "a+");
        fwrite($write, "<b>$name<br>$email<br>$url<br></b>$message<br> ");
        fclose($write);

        $read = fopen("../database/fnaticcomments.txt", "r+t");
        echo "All comments:";

        while(!feof($read)){
        echo fread($read, 1024);
        }
        fclose($read);
        }

        else{

        // $read = fopen("../database/fnaticcomments.txt", "r+t");
        echo "All comments:";

        // while(!feof($read)){
        // echo fread($read, 1024);
        }
        fclose($read);
        }
        ?>
```

If someone could help me it would be much appreciated.

*The errors I'm getting are:

(1)Warning: fopen(../database/fnaticcomments.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/delpilam/public_html/firstProject/php/fnaticpage.php on line 95

(2)Warning: feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/delpilam/public_html/firstProject/php/fnaticpage.php on line 98

(3)Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/delpilam/public_html/firstProject/php/fnaticpage.php on line 99

Comment: What is the error you getting ?

Comment: Try `error_reporting(E_ALL)` for checking error

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen - I editted in what the errors are at the bottom of my question

Comment: @NarendraSisodia - I editted in what the errors are at the bottom of my question

Comment: @MarkD if your database folder is in the same directory as your php script, you should use './database/snaticcomments.txt' instead of double dots at the start. Double dots will refer to the parent directory.

Comment: @Alan yes my database folder is in the parent.

Answer (score 2):

In else condition you are trying to read a file which does not exists if no comment is added, add a file_exists check

**try this:**

```
<?php
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $url = $_POST["url"];
        $message = $_POST["message"];
        $post = $_POST["post"];

        if($post){

        $write = fopen("../database/fnaticcomments.txt", "a+");
        fwrite($write, "<b>$name<br>$email<br>$url<br></b>$message<br> ");
        fclose($write);

        $read = fopen("../database/fnaticcomments.txt", "r+t");
        echo "All comments:";

        while(!feof($read)){
        echo fread($read, 1024);
        }
        fclose($read);
        }

        else{

         if(file_exists("../database/fnaticcomments.txt")) {

          $read = fopen("../database/fnaticcomments.txt", "r+t");
          echo "All comments:";

           while(!feof($read)){
            echo fread($read, 1024);
           }
           fclose($read);

         } else {
            echo "No comments";
         }

        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Well the file is created... I added the errors I'm getting at the bottom of my question, if those could help you understand what is going wrong...

Comment: please give your folder permission.. from shell type chmod 755 database/fnaticcomments.txt  or through php code you can do chmod("../database/fnaticcomments.txt", 0755);  after file is created..